# Info needed on deployment instructions of webrtc's apprtc - https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc on MAC OS

Tags: git, macos, webrtc, collider, apprtcdemo

1. I have cloned the git repo of apprtc - https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc
2. Altered the code to include status messages
3. Run the code locally successfully - it works fine on local host. 
4. Stuck trying to deploy the code online

I am trying to deploy this code using a MAC OS. Stuck with collider building instruction - go get collidermain. 
Does anyone have detailed instructions on how to deploy this code? At what point do you need to use and how to use google app engine/ google cloud engine to deploy the code?

Novice here so any sort of help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you find the answer for this? can you please share the sample app. Thanks!